# Adding a UIButton to a UIScrollView stops it from scrolling

Tags: objective-c, button, uiscrollview, uibutton, scrollview

I'm very new to programming and objective C so you'll have to go easy on me. I'm sure some of the code in the app is probably unnecessary. I've searched google and StackOverflow for an answer but none of the solutions have worked for me, either because they're not the right solution or I just misunderstand the answers.

The problem is that when I add an image that is very long and I want to scroll ONLY vertically, it initially refuses to scroll until I change a "constraint" called "Vertical Space (-1678) - Scroll View - Image View - Ruler pic.png" to 0 for a reason unknown to me. I don't even understand why it defaults it as -1678.

Anyway, it then works perfectly until I add a `UIButton` in the storyboard (to which I later want to add a modal "action segue" so that it will go to another view). When I've added `UIButton` it won't scroll at all in the simulator.

I suppose I must have done something wrong because I've only entered one line of code (declaring it) regarding the button, or maybe I have to put some more code in for it to scroll. I don't know! If you need more information in order to help I'll be happy to provide it. I'm fed up with trying to make it work. Thanks in advance.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {

ADBannerView *adView;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
IBOutlet UIButton *proVersion;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize bannerIsVisible;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Hide status bar:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

// iAd:
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50.0f);
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;

    }
}

 -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
if (self.bannerIsVisible) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a bit and fiddled around with the example in the answer and I got to this code:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,2246);
```

which worked! I spent days working on this and it was just one blasted little line of code. I put it into the viewDidLoad and all of a sudden it was scrolling. I also had to turn of "AutoLayout".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `ContentSize` of the `ScrollView`, like this:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
```

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. I have tried that already but putting it in the "- (void)viewDidLoad" section. Is that the correct place to put it?

Comment: Well it hasn't worked unfortunately. I'm really confused as to what's going wrong. Thanks anyway.